# Simple one-liner to run VM via Docker from scratch

Tags: linux, command-line, virtualbox, shell, docker

I'm looking for a simple command to initialize, run and log-in into newly created Docker VM preferably without creating any files (any Linux).

So basically something equivalent to the following Vagrant commands:

```
vagrant init ubuntu/vivid64 && vagrant up --provider virtualbox && vagrant ssh
```

Is there any simple way to achieve the same with Docker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
docker pull ubuntu:vivid && docker run -it ubuntu:vivid bash
```